# R variables not recognized on my Python chunk (reticulate)

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, rstudio, reticulate

My question is pretty naive, but I cannot think of why I am getting this error.
I am using the reticulate library to use a python script within R for a project. For a very practical reason, I want to code one last chunk in python. But when i try to call an R variable that was defined previously (using r.var), it seems like python does not recognize the r variable.

Example with a very basic variable here:

[image]

Does anyone has an answer to this ?

Thanks in advance